# Using git push feature

Tags: git, push, git-branch

I was wondering what is the interpretation of `git push origin master`.

I mean we `push` the commits to the `origin` repo's `master` branch.

But suppose, there's a branch `A`.

I create a new branch `B` keeping `A` as the base branch. (`git checkout -b B A`)

Now, whether I should do `git push origin A` or `git push origin master` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `git push origin B`.

The last parameter means to which branch you're sending the commits.

If you use `master`, it will try to sent the commits to the master branch on the remote side, possibly returning an error if it's not a fast-forward.